# How to rig Strapped bag

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves, rigid-body-simulation

I'm animating a shot with a female character, who has a bag on her shoulder.
And here's my rig :

Rig File :
[image]

[image: The bag]

so it will be on her left shoulder and hanging down around her left hip. which i solve this by creating a root bone.

and here's the problem :

since I'm using curve (bezier) and bevel object
-  the strap bevel is a rectangle and the strap cannot be rotated
- and if I scale the bag the strap cannot be scaled even i tried to parent bevel object with root bone...
- I also don't know how to rig strap if i apply curves modifier into mesh

Plus one and the most important
I also want to know how to simulate the rig.. or make this rig dynamic, so i don't need to animate the rig, maybe only cleaning up the movements

Thank You!

Comment: Did you try using a hook modifier ?

Comment: yes, i use hook modifier but still cant rotate...